# NodeJS http module vs Nginx Server

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy, server

I have read that proxies can be created by Nginx server for nodejs application to listen on but I am doubtful as to what exactly this will serve additional purpose and advantages compared to http module provide by nodejs for listening purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, you can serve multiple Node applications on one server, with host based virtual servers managed by nginx, so that requests to the same port but with different `Host:` HTTP header reach different Node applications.

Also nginx can be set up to serve static assets without hitting your Node app and do some caching if you need it.

Those are two things that you can achieve with adding nginx to the mix but you may not need that in your case. Also, you can run a reverse proxy with Node and without nginx if that's what you prefer.